# No reducer provided for key {name}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have set up my redux store and everything seems alright all imports and exports seems correct to me but I do not seem to have a valid reducer and sagas. Been stuck, what am I doing wrong?

I get this error message [image]

I have a store with the file structure below

#### Store

- configStore.js
- index.js

```
import { applyMiddleware, compose, createStore } from 'redux';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from '../components/rootReducer';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
    return {
        ...createStore(
            rootReducer,
            initialState,
            composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
        ),
        runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run,
    };
}
```

```
import configureStore from './configStore';
import rootSaga from '../components/rootSaga';

const store = configureStore({});
store.runSaga(rootSaga);

export default store;
```

rootSaga

```
import { all } from 'redux-saga/effects';

import planets from './planets';

export default function* rootSaga() {
    yield all([
        planets.sagas(),
    ]);
}
```

rootReducer

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import planets from './planets';

export default combineReducers({
    planets: planets.reducers,
});
```

In my components I have

reducers.js

```
import { UPDATE_PLANETS, LOAD_PLANETS } from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    isPlanetsLoading: false,
    planets: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
    switch (type) {
        case LOAD_PLANETS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isPlanetsLoading: true,
            };
        case UPDATE_PLANETS:
            return {
                ...state,
                isPlanetsLoading: false,
                planets: payload,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

Planets.js

```
import { List } from "antd";
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { requestPlanets } from '../actions';

const Planets = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const { planets } = useSelector(
    (state) => state.planets
  );
  console.log(planets);

  useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(requestPlanets());
  }, [dispatch, planets]);
// return statement
};

export default Planets;
```

Comment: In rootSaga, you are doing planets.sagas(). But that is not a valid function

Comment: @ZabeehUllahBabar it is still saying there is no valid reducer, On the redux dev tools there is nothing in the store. Just empty state

Answer (score 0):

1. `createStore` returns the store. So don't spread it. Just associate the output of createStore to an object property say store.
2. in index.js, destructure the configStore object `{ store, runSaga }`

**configStore**

```js
export default function configureStore(initialState) {
    const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
    const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
    return {
        store: createStore(
            rootReducer,
            initialState,
            composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)),
        ),
        runSaga: sagaMiddleware.run,
    };
}
```

**index.js**

```js
import configureStore from './configStore';
import rootSaga from '../components/rootSaga';

const { store, runSaga } = configureStore({});
runSaga(rootSaga);


export default store;
```